# Typescript returning boolean after promise resolved

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise, ionic3, ionic-storage

I'm trying to return a boolean after a promise resolves but typescript gives an error saying

`A 'get' accessor must return a value.`

my code looks like.

```
get tokenValid(): boolean {
    // Check if current time is past access token's expiration
    this.storage.get('expires_at').then((expiresAt) => {
      return Date.now() < expiresAt;
    }).catch((err) => { return false });
}
```

This code is for Ionic 3 Application and the storage is Ionic Storage instance.

Comment: You can't do this... You can return a `Promise<boolean>` by just returning `this.storage.get...` though.

Comment: @user2473015  I've not usually seen asynchronous code inside of a get, rather the async process sets a property, that the get retrieves...

Comment: And you probably shouldn't use a getter for a thing that has side effects.

Comment: @bergi It does not look to me like the code inside `tokenValid` is causing side effects. Can you provide more details.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin it queries the storage (which takes time) and can change at any time

Comment: @Bergi The vocabulary here is unclear to me. I was under the impression that side effects refer to causing mutations outside the function's body. What you're referring to seems more like a violation of referential transparency, unless a query to the storage is causing the storage to change.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes, that's a more accurate description. I used "side effect" because a) time is often considered as one b) we indeed don't know what a query does (and "sending a request" could be an action that mutates all kinds of stuff, at least on the lower levels).

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the additional details. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Bergi Is there way to use this code, not as a getter and making it function with this async behavior and return boolean?

Comment: @user2473015 No, when it's asynchronous it has to return a promise for the boolean. To make it a method, just omit the `get`.

Comment: @Bergi Can I use async/await and make this call synchronous?

Comment: @user2473015 No, it's impossible to make it synchronous. Using `async`/`await` syntax only is sugar for `then` calls - it's still asynchronous and returns a promise.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can return a `Promise` that resolves to a boolean like this:

```
get tokenValid(): Promise<boolean> {
  // |
  // |----- Note this additional return statement. 
  // v
  return this.storage.get('expires_at')
    .then((expiresAt) => {
      return Date.now() < expiresAt;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return false;
    });
}
```

The code in your question only has two return statements: one inside the Promise's `then` handler and one inside its `catch` handler. We added a third return statement inside the `tokenValid()` accessor, because the accessor needs to return something too.

Here is a working example [in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20StorageManager%20%7B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20stub%20out%20storage%20for%20the%20demo%0D%0A%20%20private%20storage%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%3A%20(prop%3A%20string)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve(Date.now()%20%2B%2086400000)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20tokenValid()%3A%20Promise%3Cboolean%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.storage.get('expires_at')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((expiresAt)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Date.now()%20%3C%20expiresAt%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.catch((err)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20manager%20%3D%20new%20StorageManager()%3B%0D%0Amanager.tokenValid.then((result)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20window.alert(result)%3B%20%2F%2F%20true%0D%0A%7D)%3B):

```
class StorageManager { 

  // stub out storage for the demo
  private storage = {
    get: (prop: string): Promise<any> => { 
      return Promise.resolve(Date.now() + 86400000);
    }
  };

  get tokenValid(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.storage.get('expires_at')
      .then((expiresAt) => {
        return Date.now() < expiresAt;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return false;
      });
  }
}

const manager = new StorageManager();
manager.tokenValid.then((result) => { 
  window.alert(result); // true
});
```

Comment: @user2473015 I'm afraid I don't know what additional information to provide in this answer.

Comment: This won't pass a tslint test considering Promise<boolean> is not the only possible return type.  Better to use Promise<any>

Answer (score 11):

Your function should be:

```
get tokenValid(): Promise<Boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.storage.get('expires_at')
        .then((expiresAt) => {
          resolve(Date.now() < expiresAt);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(false);
      });
 });
}
```

Comment: Hello, if I change the code `reject(false);` to `reject(err)`, can I get the false value?

Comment: No, the parameter of reject function must be the same as the return type of your function.

Comment: Okay, if we don't use `resolve` or `reject`, is that okay? I mean we just return a bool value and not pass `resolve` or `reject`. If so, what is the propose of resolve?

Comment: As you can see i return new Promise class, so i need to call resolve or reject. If you want to return only value true or false, you just write: this.storage.get('expires_at')
        .then((expiresAt) => {
          return Date.now() < expiresAt;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return false;
      });