# return Boolean according to promise result

Tags: reactjs, promise, es6-promise, mobx-react, tsx

I got confused here in handling promise.
I have a function that returns boolean, regarding what the result of the promise is (it is part of mobx store actions)

so here if the length is bigger than zero I want to return true else return false.  but of course, before promise gets resolved, false is returned

```
@action
  public isUserAdmin(): boolean {
    this.user!.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
      return idTokenResult.groups.length > 0;
    });
    return false;
  }
```

I got confused in using await, async or none of them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return from a promise then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then)

Comment: @trincot please mark as duplicate if the question has at least accepted answer, otherwise, there are hundreds of questions regarding promises

Comment: The duplicate mark is valid. The aim is to minimise the number of duplicate questions regarding promises. It is not needed that the referenced question has an accepted answer (which anyway is subjective choice of the asker). In fact, it is just a special case of this more [generic Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) where the accepted answer has a section on the specific case of promises.

Comment: @trincot I don't think this is a duplicate isn't it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520739/promise-async-await-boolean-returns-false-but-if-condition-still-gets-called

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45665478/1624844) seems it is somehow impossible to return boolean directly from the function so changed to

```
      @action
      public isUserAdmin(): Promise<boolean> {
-ret-->   return this.user!.getIdTokenResult()
          .then((idTokenResult) => {
            return idTokenResult.groups.length > 0;
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            return false;
          });
      }
```

then inside component get it as

```
  myStore!.isUserAdmin().then((result) => {
  /* and this result is wanted boolean */
});
```